# StaticResource Lookup not working with merged dictionaries

Tags: wpf, resources, static, mergeddictionaries

I have been reading up on this for a while now, but I can't seem to find an answer that can help me, so I hope that I will be having more luck here.

In my project I have a Library which contains a lot of styles for controls. These Styles use resources as static resource. So the "resource tree" basically looks like this:

- Theme.xaml

  - SizeResources.xaml
  - ColorResources.xaml
  - ControlStyles.xaml

    - Control1.xaml
    - Control2.xaml

Theme.xaml merges SizeResources, ColorResources and ControlStyles. ControlStyles merge all xamls for the specific controls.

Now in my Application I would like to apply that theme so OnStartup I add the Theme.xaml to my Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries. Which works fine, all keys are there. When I am now trying to use the Controls I get an Exception that for example a Size or Color Resource can not be found. Specific Example:

I have a special button which has a background color that is defined in ColorResources, my ButtonStyle uses this resource as static resource. When I use that Button in my application project I get an exception that the Background resource can not be found. When I change static resource to dynamic resource in control1.xaml then it works.

Any Ideas why I can't do this with static resource? From my understanding, static should work aswell.

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to define:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource SpecialBackgroundBrush}"/>
```

instead of your `Button`, does it work? I suspect it will. Assuming it does, what you need to do is ensure the `Button` style itself has static access to the brushes. Thus, in your *Button.xaml* you need something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ColorResources"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It would be useful to see examples of your XAML if this doesn't help.

Comment: Hey, you actually provided a very good example. My Xaml looks about the same as the example you provided. So basically my question is, why do I need to Merge the ColorResources into the file that contains my Button style when I merge the ColorResources as well as the Button resource on application level into one merged dictionary. Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries.add(Theme.xaml) To use my example above. Theme.xaml provides the color resources, why do I have to merge them into the button xaml?

Comment: Because that's not statically accessible, at least not from the perspective of the XAML compiler compiling the button resources in isolation from anything else. It needs to resolve any static resources referenced by the button just by looking at your Button resource dictionary, not at your application-level one.

Comment: So the compiler basically starts at the leaves of the resource dictionary tree and starts compiling upwards. So if I include my Colors.xaml within the button, the Colors.xaml gets compiled without problems then next in line is the Button dictionary itself which references the colors. It can then be compiled without problems because all Colors have been compiled and are available for it. If I do not merge the colors within the Button, the Button dictionary is compiled without resources, as all the resources that are merged into the tree further up are not available at compilation time?

Answer (score 0):

Even the dynamic resources have this shortcoming of not being found in the neighbouring merged dictionaries. But the real problem here lies in skinning. What if you only want to change the colours, but not the control templates - which in turn depend on those colours?

One can separate colours and templates into two XAML files, but which "Color" XAML file shall the templates file include, if you have several of these Color files (one per skin)?